# could i have to send all the source code of the application who has just one gpl library?

Tags: open-source, licensing, lgpl

I was evaluating ZK framework, which is LGPL and it's spring plugin zk-spring is GPL.

If i develop a system with different application like domain, web(zk, zk-spring), web-services. Now When I deploy these application on the client machine, would i have to also provide all the source code of my applications to the client? I also want to keep proprietary of code to myself.

Or Should i buy license and can own my application code and don't have to use the GPL.

I am not clear so, please answer my all concerns and issue involved here.

looking forward to hear from you soon and thanks in advance.

Comment: You really just need to read the license. It's not a simple question and there's no simple answer. It hinges on many complex details about how you use the library.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [licensing advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) You may be able to get help on [Programmers Stack Exchange, but **read their faq carefully** before proceeding.](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/when-is-a-software-licensing-question-on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to distribute any work that is derivative of, or contains sufficient protectable expressive content taken from, a work covered by the GPL, you must also distribute the source code of that work, even if you wrote it. There really is no better answer possible. If you need an opinion that you can legally rely on, consult an attorney.

Comment: http://gpl-violations.org/faq/sourcecode-faq.html

Comment: @vicky: The problem with that FAQ is it botches the key question. If you read the first two paragraphs of the answer to "What kind of source code do I have to publish under the GNU GPL?" you can see that it confuses the work you're distributing with the work that was placed under the GPL.